# Cannot find boost shared library files in Android application

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

For Intellij (and Android Studio) I built a JNI shared library that links to boost libraries that I'd link to include in my Android app. I called **System.loadLibrary** on my .so file but it fails to find boost libraries when I run it. I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libboost_unit_test_framework-clang-mt-x32-1_77.so.1.77.0" not found: needed by /data/app/~~28p8gv9ihFbZAejYd9c9yw==/sensoft.applications.dt1demo-0IEJ8o6cHOk0kputNbnbNQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86/libssi_utils_java.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

Even though the boost .so files are there in the **libs/x86** directory (I built them in x86 with the android toolchain to run on my emulator) but it did manage to find the .so file that I built in the same directory.

I placed my .so file and all the required boost .so files in the **libs/x86** directory and included the following as a jni source in my build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
```

But my application can't seem to find the boost shared libraries specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's install process will not extract libraries that don't have the suffix `.so`. You have to remove the version suffix of the library (which serves no purpose on Android anyway, because libraries are not all installed to a single common path).

Comment: Thanks Dan, when I unpack the apk on the device, I noticed that the boost so files were not added when they had the version suffix added to the file name, but when I removed it, it was added to the apk file